# APNS Connection failed. Working on mac, Not on server. Ports are open.

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I have been trying to send push notification on my server but I get this error

Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection timed out) in /home/mialkan/public_html/pushPro.php on line 15
Failed to connect: 110 Connection timed out

Here is my php.

```
<?php
   function sendNotificationiOS ($deviceToken,$message){


 // Put your private key's passphrase here:
  $passphrase = 'passcode';
  $ctx = stream_context_create();
  stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ckPro.pem');
  stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

 // Open a connection to the APNS server
  $fp = stream_socket_client(
   'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

  if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

   echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

 // Create the payload body
  $body['aps'] = array(
   'alert' => $message,
   'sound' => 'default'
  );

 // Encode the payload as JSON
 $payload = json_encode($body);

 // Build the binary notification
  $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) .      $payload;

  // Send it to the server
  $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

  if (!$result)
     echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
  else
     echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

 // Close the connection to the server
 fclose($fp);

}
 sendNotificationiOS('devicetoken','first pushNotification')
?>
```

I installed the Entrust Ca. pem file working properly on my mac.

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apple APNS, on sever cant send push notification with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743502/apple-apns-on-sever-cant-send-push-notification-with-php)